# Using MVVM to Solve Combobox Interaction

Tags: wpf, vb.net, mvvm, combobox

I'm new to WPF and I haven't used MVVM yet but I think I'm in a situation where it might help.

In my program I've got several comboboxes that all have the same comboboxitems and when the user makes a selection in one of the comboboxes the selected comboboxitem gets disabled in the other comboboxes. (i.e. If the user has selected the comboboxitem with value 'a' in combobox #1 and selected the comboboxitem with value 'b' in combobox #2 then in remaining comboboxes both the comboboxitems with values 'a' and 'b' are disabled)

Anyway, I'm having trouble doing this programmatically in the code-behind and I was hoping someone could describe how to approach this problem using MVVM.

Thanks
MG

Comment: Before this can reasonably be answered, I think it would help if you posted some of your code, where you try to use MVVM concepts to do this. I would like to see a simplified version of your ViewModel Class, and the xaml for the View.

Comment: Also your question title isn't very descriptive.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - I changed the title of the question. Also, I'm wondering if this problem is easily solved in MVVM as I haven't started using MVVM yet. (My sample code isn't in MVVM.)

Comment: All I'm looking for is a high-level description of how this would be done in MVVM...just a way to point me in the right direction as I get started in MVVM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one of the [best primers on MVVM applied to WPF, with first rate code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx).

It isn't a quick read, and don't get frustrated if even seemingly simple things take some time to grok.

To answer your question more directly, you use MVVM to make data binding work (not to mention your logic testable). So for a ComboBox, you firstly supply it with data. probably using an ObservableCollection which has support for data binding in it. You can synchronize the Selected Item(s) in the ComboBox(es) to a property(ies) in your view model, and change the contents of one based on a change in the Selected Item.

Suggest you read that article and work through some code, then follow up with some more targeted questions using code.

HTH,
Berryl